# How to clean GCP Project Resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to delete all resources of the **GCP Project** that are created on a specific date. How I can delete all resources in a GCP project?

I do not want to delete GCP Project, because a single project shares multiple times after an interval of time.

Setup GCP account for student practice.

Comment: simply delete the project, or at least the billing account to stop being billed for the resources.

Comment: GCP have any project limit creation? GCP allowed to created of unlimited projects.

Comment: Refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/limits) helpful to you

Comment: When you delete a project, the project still exists for 30 days in a deleted state to support recovery but you are not charged for those resources. I think the maximum number of projects for a non-organization identity is 30 total projects.

Comment: I am using organization, if I delete project the project, can I get unlimited access of project creation in gcp. Because we are building gcp cloud learning solution for remote users?

Comment: That detail should have been in your original question. Organizations have a project quota. You must look up your project quota remaining on the New Project page. Refer to these links: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/limits and https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7283050?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this. Simply go to "IAM & Admin" -> "Manage Resources". This will take you to a management screen for your projects and you can delete them, see the billing, etc.

Comment: I want to clean Project using CLI, using projectID, not want to clean resources using connsole.

Comment: @AsifKhalil I want to know whether you want to delete project or resources in the project in gcp

Comment: I am creating a GCP learning solution, a GCP project is shared with the student for 2 to 3 hours of access to explore GCP resources, after the end of his practice I want to clean all GCP project resources that he has created during practice. 
Then i want to share same project to next user, with empty resources.